# Solution of $p(z)=0$ with $z\in\mathbb C$ and $a_k\in\mathbb R$ for all $k$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

Suppose $p(z)=a_0+...+a_nz^n$ with $a_k\in\mathbb R$ for all $k$.

How can I prove that if   $p(z)=0$ then $p(\bar z)=0$? I know it's true, but how can I prove it?

Comment: You need to assume $a_0,\cdots, a_n\in\mathbb{R}.$ In other case it is false. Just consider $p(z)=z-i.$ To solve your question, with real coefficients, show that $0=\overline{p(z)}=p(\bar{z}).$

Comment: ok fine, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$p(\bar z) = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^n {{a_i}{{\bar z}^i}} $$now, if ${a_i} \in \mathbb{R}$, then ${a_i} = \overline {{a_i}} $ so that $$p(\bar z) = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^n {{{\bar a}_i}{{\bar z}^i}} $$now, for any pair of complex numbers $a$ and $b$, we have $$\begin{array}{l}\overline {a \times b}  = \overline {({x_a} + i{y_a}) \times ({x_b} + i{y_b})}  = \overline {({x_a}{x_b} - {y_a}{y_b}) + i({x_a}{y_b} + {x_b}{y_a})}  = \\({x_a}{x_b} - {y_a}{y_b}) - i({x_a}{y_b} + {x_b}{y_a}) = \overline {({x_a} + i{y_a})}  \times \overline {({x_b} + i{y_b})}  = \overline a  \times \overline b \end{array}$$so by replacing into our equation, we get $$p(\bar z) = \overline {\sum\limits_{i = 0}^n {{a_i}{z^i}} }  = \overline {p(z)}  = 0$$Hope it helps ;)